# Verify shutdown command

Tags: linux, shutdown

On linux, you can do a `shutdown -r 17:00` to reboot at 5pm. Every so often there will be a message that appears system wide that says `System will go down in X minutes`.

Is there a way to force this message to appear or verify that a `shutdown -r 17:00 &` is running in the background without cancelling the current shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify jobs that are running in the background by using the command:

`jobs`

Like this:

`root@server1:/var/www/nodebb# jobs
[1]+  Running                 shutdown -r 17:00 &`

Here is a good resource on learning how to use jobs, and manage background jobs in general:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/

Keep in mind that the job is tied to your session, if you close it ( AKA close the shell ) your job wont run. A better option for me would be to use cron to schedule the reboot.

Edit your crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

Now enter the cron entry... this will reboot the box every day at 5pm. (17:00)

```
*   17  *   *   *   shutdown
```

Thats it for cron! You can view your crontab via:

```
crontab -l
```

Comment: This command doesn't appear to be in Debian. Does it have synonyms?

Comment: @AWippler - What shell are you using? I believe this is part of the bash shell: echo $SHELL to see which shell you use.

Comment: /bin/bash is what I am using on this rpi. `ps aux | grep shutdown` is similar to jobs; however, this doesn't push out the global shut down message.

Comment: Well the `ps` command just shows processes, so it's not an alternative. Try this: `ps aux | grep shutdown | grep -v grep` and I bet that comes back with nothing. Essentially when you grep, that is also a process, so you're probably just getting your grep process returned and not the shutdown process. The `-v grep` says omit the grep process.

Comment: Do an `apt-cache search jobs` and see what packages come back, maybe there is something that you can install that is the jobs command itself or similar. Or just use Cron.